# Increase in InnoDB Row Operations

Tags: mysql, join, row, innodb

We have almost doubled the InnoDB Row Operations (Rows read) after a change.

The question I have is what exactly is this number representing. Is it the rows returned from the queries or is it the number of rows touched by the queries in different tables.
We have introduced new tables to join. This should not have changed the amount of returned rows but clearly the amount of touched rows in the different tables.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the storage engine level (e.g. InnoDB), rows read refers to the physical rows read from *each* table. These rows are returned by the storage engine to the SQL layer of MySQL, where they are joined or filtered out by the conditions in your query.

So it makes perfect sense that your rows read figure would increase when you join to a new table. It's counting rows read from each table.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Bill, I think that, with ICP, the rows are not necessarily returned to the Handler layer.  The counts at that layer come from the collection of `STATUS` values in `Handler_read%`.

Comment: You're probably right. But in any case, this supports the idea that the total count is the rows read from each table, not the rows of result set.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `EXPLAIN` to check how your join is behaving.
For understanding, output format refer [here](https://www.eversql.com/mysql-explain-example-explaining-mysql-explain-using-stackoverflow-data/) and [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/explain-output.html)